# Setting DIV to display:none if it contains a UL list that does not contains any LI items

Tags: wordpress, list, hide, element, wrapper

I am designing a WordPress theme and have this problem : The sidebar has some DIV containers which all have one UL list. But one of these UL lists has no LI items. Now I want to hide the DIV container that has this UL list without LI items.

I was trying this, but it failed to work:

```css
.wrapper > aside > div > div:not(h3 ul li) {display:none;}<br />
```

Example code:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
    <div class="sidebar-widget">
      <div id="recent-comments-2" class="widget_recent_comments">
        <h3>Recent Comments</h3>
        <ul id="recentcomments"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so I'm assuming the empty <ul> is **going** to have list items at some point? If so you can put an if statement to determine whether there is going to be any <li>'s added (eg. if there are posts, add the <ul> with posts listed in <li>'s) and if there are none then don't display the <ul> at all?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know how to change the standard WordPress function get_sidebar();. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through PHP code or if you want a much simpler approach, then use jQuery. It would check that if the `UL` has `li` as its children with this function `.hasChildren()`. Thus it will turn it into `display:block`, otherwise `display:none`